# Reset component into modal

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I have a component that is inserted in a modal and that includes a CheckListBox. When the modal starts each time, the component is not reset. How can I do? How Force reset? I use reactjs with hooks.
How can I trigger a reset event every time the modal opens?
Thanks a lot.

```
    const CheckList = ({title, api, color, onChange }) => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    let listCheck = [];

    useEffect(() => {

        axiosApi.get( `${api}`).then((res)=>{
              setItems(res.data);      
        })
      }, [])

    function handleClick(ev, item) {

        if  (ev.target.checked) {
            listCheck.push(item)
            onChange(listCheck);
          }
          else 
          {

            listCheck = listCheck.filter(riga => {
                  return (riga.id !== item.id)});
             onChange(listCheck);
          }
    }

        return (    
            <> 

<div class="card rd-card-list">
 <div  class="card-header">
    {title}
 </div>

  <div  class="card-content rd-card-content">
     <div class="content rd-scroll">
       <ul class="rd-ul">

       {  items.map( (item) =>   
                          <li class="rd-li" key={item.id}>
                          <label class="checkbox">
                            {item.description}
                           </label>
                           <input type="checkbox" onClick={(ev) => handleClick(ev, item)}/>
                       </li>
                       )
                      }
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</>

        );
  }

  export default CheckList;
```

in my modal.js

```
   <CheckList  title="mytititle" api="/api/users" onChange={(itx) => {
                  formik.setFieldValue('users', itx)
             } }/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to not render the modal until it's open:

```
<div>
    {modalOpen &&
        <Modal open={modalOpen}>
           <CheckList  title="mytititle" api="/api/users" onChange={(itx) => {
              formik.setFieldValue('users', itx)
            } }/> 
        </Modal>
    }
</div>
```

So whenever you close the modal, it will be removed from DOM, along with any data that this component had.

Comment: No, the modal in that mode don't remove from DOM and when you open another times the fields is not reset. Why? Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with Modal code and how you are calling it.

Answer (score 0):

React life cycle events can be used to perform operation before a component can be rendered. 'constructor()' or 'componentDidMount()' can be used in class components to reset the data or any other operation before rendering the component.

Since you are using function component, you can use React hooks to mimic the life cycle events using 'useEffect()'.